# Run a Javascript function after a default jQuery function is run

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

in jQuery; How would I execute a function once a specific function is run. For example; everytime `.text()` is run, can I run a function no-matter the context?

In this specific example i'm looking to listen to `.append()`, reason being I need to re-register event listeners when new elements are placed on the screen. (i.e. btn click event listeners).

How can I accomplish this? Let us use `refreshEvents()` as an example function.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use event delegation

Comment: You would have to redefine `$.fn.append()` to do what you want, then call the old value of `$.fn.append()`. Are you sure you can't do what you want using event delegation?

Comment: Hi @adeneo, Please find my comment under Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the right way to do what you want is with event delegation, as described in [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). E.g. change

```
$(".search-btn").on("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

to:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".search-btn", function() {
    ...
});
```

Replace `#container` with a selector for a static element that contains all the dynamically-added search buttons.

But to show how to do what you asked, you can do:

```
(function(oldappend) {
    $.fn.append = function() {
        var result = oldappend.apply(this, arguments);
        refreshEvents();
        return result;
    };
})($.fn.append);
```

This saves the original value of the jQuery `.append()` method in the local variable `oldappend`, then redefines it to a function that calls the original function and then calls your function.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thanks for the event note. I currently have events though; however they aren't working as they are run on document.ready() and once new elements are generated the events no-longer work on the new buttons. 

        $(".search-btn").on('click', function () {
                alert("test");
        });

Once there is a new search-btn, it doesn't work unless I rerun the function.

Comment: That's why you should use event delegation, as explained in the linked question.

Comment: $('body').on('click','.search-btn',fn)

Comment: Apologies - i totally misread the second argument. This is AMAZING. Thank you!